# Orchestrator function failed: The activity function failed: "Unable to resolve function name"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a working azure functions app where I added a sub-orchestrator with activity functions inside. The rest of the app is working just fine, but not the added code. From the logs, I can see that the sub-orchestrator is reached, but when it tries to hit the activity function, it throws the error below.

> > Function 'TestActivity (Orchestrator)' failed with an error. Reason: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.FunctionFailedException: The activity function 'GetStringInput' failed: "Unable to resolve function name 'GetStringInput'.". See the function execution logs for additional details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve function name 'GetStringInput'. at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.FunctionInstanceLogger.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\Diagnostics\FunctionInstanceLogger.cs:line 80

Here's the client orchestrator:

```
[FunctionName(FUNC_INITIALIZE)]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> InitializeAsync(HttpRequestMessage req,
            [OrchestrationClient(TaskHub = "%Name%")]
            DurableOrchestrationClientBase client,
            ILogger logger)
{
  var body = new BodyObject {Something:"inside"};
  var instance_id = await client.StartNewAsync(FUNC_RELEASE, body);
  return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

Orchestrator:

```
[FunctionName(FUNC_RELEASE)]
public static async Task<string> Release(
                                   [OrchestrationTrigger]  DurableOrchestrationContextBase ctx,
                                   ILogger log)
{
  var ctx_obj = ctx.GetInput<BodyObject>();
  var response = await ctx.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<int>(FUNC_ORCHESTRATE_MORE, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ctx_json));
  //do stuff with response
  return new ResultObject = {Result:"response"};
}
```

Another Orchestrator:

```
[FunctionName(FUNC_ORCHESTRATE_MORE)]
public static async Task<string> OrchestrateMore(
                                   [OrchestrationTrigger]  
                                   DurableOrchestrationContextBase ctx,
                                   ILogger log)
{
  var input = ctx.GetInput<string>();
  //do stuff
  var inpu_json = JsonConvert.SerilializeObject(input);
  var response = await ctx.CallActivityAsync<int>(FUNC_ACTIVITY, input_json);
  //do stuff with response
  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ResultObject = {Result:"response"});
}
```

Activity

```
[FunctionName(FUNC_ACTIVITY)]
public static async Task<string> DoingActivity(
                                   [ActivityTrigger]  string input,
                                   ILogger log)
{
  //do stuff with input
  return string_of_info;
}
```

From the portal, I can see that the activity functions exist and are enabled. Changing the signature of the activity functions to use the type `DurableActivityContext` yielded the same results. Submitting the request from inside the portal itself yielded a 404 not found error only on the activities added, not on existing activities.

Other info:

```
.NET 472,
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs v2.3.0,
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Http v1.2.0,
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask v1.8.4
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus v2.2.0
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions v1.0.29
```

App is being deployed through Azure DevOps.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Something doesn't add up in the code, you are sending parameters which doesn't exist like "input_json", "ctx_json". Also the signature of the Functions you defined, doesn't match what you are calling like "Task<string> DoingActivity" and CallActivityAsync<int>

Comment: @BassamGamal I edited the post per your comment.  Thanks!

Comment: Try adding doblequotes to the name of the function or activity. var response = await ctx.CallActivityAsync<int>("FUNC_ACTIVITY", input_json);